# generate different results using three columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an invoice based on Excel data (attached). I required a MySQL query that can generate different results using three columns. Functional requirement is as follows:

The Excel file has a column called KM (Kilometer), city and total_amount

If a person travel DXB (Dubai) the rates from total_amount column would be like this

```
1-3 Kms the rate is 9
4-5 Kms the rate is 11
6-7 Kms the rate is 13
```

For AUH (Abu Dhabi) different rates but same process. So the query will count all the entries of 1-3, 4-5, 6-7 and vice-versa (see sample invoice).

So far, I wrote separate queries for Dubai. See below:

```
SELECT city, count(KM), sum(total_amount), total_amount*count(KM), total_amount*count(KM), round(total_amount*count(KM)*0.05,2), total_amount*count(KM)*0.05+(total_amount*count(KM)) FROM perorder where city like '%XB' and KM between 1 and 3 GROUP BY CITY

SELECT city, count(KM), sum(total_amount), total_amount*count(KM), total_amount*count(KM), round(total_amount*count(KM)*0.05,2), total_amount*count(KM)*0.05+(total_amount*count(KM)) FROM perorder where city like '%XB' and KM between 4 and 5 GROUP BY CITY

SELECT city, count(KM), sum(total_amount), total_amount*count(KM), total_amount*count(KM), round(total_amount*count(KM)*0.05,2), total_amount*count(KM)*0.05+(total_amount*count(KM)) FROM perorder where city like '%XB' and KM between 6 and 7 GROUP BY CITY
```

I will repeat almost the same queries for Abu Dhabi, but is there a way to generate the attached invoice result by writing a single MySQL query?

Sample data in the Database

[image]

Required invoice result

[image]

Comment: you can try something like `select ....,case when KM between 1 and 3 then 1 when KM between 4 and 5 then 2 else 3 end as foo from perorder .....`

Comment: To make this work you need to think database rather than spreadsheet and store the rates in a table. Study normalisation in db design. Also when posting sample data do so as text which we can ingest and use together with table definitions (having to hand type them and guess datatypes and indexes is offputting).